# Current line number aligned to the left with number and relativenumber

Tags: vimrc, line-numbers

I use relative line numbers along with an absolute line number for the current line:

```
set number
set relativenumber
```

The absolute current line number is always aligned to the left, and the help pages (or Google) don't seem to provide an option to change this.

Is it possible to prevent this left align, or will I have to learn to live with it?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a patch is being worked on to add an option for this: https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/2204

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From `screen.c`, `win_line()` function (around line 3707):

```
/* 'number' + 'relativenumber' */
num = lnum;
fmt = "%-*ld ";
```

The `%-` makes it left-aligned (See `sprintf(3)`). As you can see, this value is hard-coded.

If you really want this, you can modify it to:

```
fmt = "%*ld ";
```

and recompile. The result should be something like:

[image]

Of course, this might make a good candidate for an option/patch :-)

Comment: How about aligning all other non-current lines to the left?

Comment: @RafiB. I don't understand your commment?

Comment: taking your screenshot for instance, aligning the line numbers 1-2 and 1-3 to the left.

Comment: @RafiB. Yes, that's possible, by modifying the source...