# vim line number digit group separator

Tags: vimrc

Is there any way to have a digit group separator for line numbers in `vim`?

i.e., if I am on line `1234567` it would become `1,234,567`, where `,` is a delimiter.

Comment: By the way, if you are really editing a file that large, I would suggest taking a look at `:h relativenumber`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is all hard-coded; see `screen.c`, line 3893:

```
char *fmt = "%*ld ";

[..]

sprintf((char *)extra, fmt, number_width(wp), num);
```

So the only way to get what you want is to modify this code.

Sorry :-(

[Related](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3516/51)